# DICOM pixel data lossless rendering and representation

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I quote :

> DICOM supports up to **65,536 (16 bits)** shades of gray for monochrome image display, thus capturing the slightest nuances in medical imaging. In comparison, converting DICOM images into JPEGs or bitmaps (limited to **256** shades of gray) often renders the images unacceptable for diagnostic reading. - Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine (DICOM): A Practical Introduction and Survival Guide by Oleg S. Pianykh

As I am a beginner in image processing I'm used to process images colored and monochrome with 256 levels, so for Dicom images, in which representation I have to process pixels without rendering them to 256 levels?, because of the loss of information.

note: If you can put a better tittle for this question, please feel free to do so, I've a hard time doing that and didn't come to a good one.

Comment: The standard method is to use "windowing" and "levelling" where you select a subset of the 16 bit range (windowing) and set the window to a particular point in the data (levelling). Look at some open source code like GDCM to see examples.

Comment: @johnelemans, for the moment I don't know much about windowing and leveling, so I do some research, thanks for you, you gave that link for examples, I love learning using examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to put the image's pixels through the Modality VOI/LUT transform in order to transform modality-dependent values to known units (e.g. Hounsfield or Optical Density).

Then, all your processing **must be done on the entire range of values (do not convert 16 bit values to 8 bit)**.

The presentation (visualization) can be performed using scaled values (using 8 bit values), usually passing the data through the Presentation VOI/LUT (window-width or LUT).

See this for the Modality transform: [rescale slope and rescale intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193971/rescale-slope-and-rescale-intercept/10197843#10197843)

See the this for Window/Width: [Window width and center calculation of DICOM image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756096/window-width-and-center-calculation-of-dicom-image/8765366#8765366)

Comment: Thank you sir, I will come up to this answer (to make it accepted) later after seeing the links and doing some research, thank you again.

Comment: I'm using Dcmtk library and i used the `getVoiLutFunction()` and this function return three different `enum` outputs (`EFV_Linear`, `EFV_Sigmoid`, `EFV_Default`), and for my current CT image I get the the `EFV_Default` value, the question is: how can I make a transformation having that function return value?

Comment: I looked into the standard documentation, and I found that a VOI LUT function can have one of three values (`LINEAR, LINEAR_EXACT, SIGMOID`), and they mention that `LINEAR` in the default one when (VOI LUT Function) attribute is absent, I'm confused, what is the matching one for DCMTK's `EFV_Default` `enum`