# Transforming raw pixel using rescale slope and rescale intercept in DIcom

Tags: image, image-processing, dicom

I used the solution in this post [Window width and center calculation of Dicom Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759043/1455335) to transform the raw pixel, it works good most of the images, but i faced problem with some images. That images having pixel value "24", rescale slope "1.0" and rescale intercept "-1024".
When i applied the solution mentioned above am get the new pixel value in negative(-1000).

I can't find the value for this new pixel value in Lookup table created by using window level and window width because look up table having only positive  values (0 to 65536). Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: The regular [Hounsfield scale for CT images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounsfield_scale) ranges from -1000 to 3095 (corresponding to 12 bits/4096 unique values). The rescaled value makes perfect sense, representing air. What is your LUT intended to represent?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably dealing with CT images. RescaleIntercept tag for CTs usually set to -1024. Negative -1000 value you obtain makes perfect sense, it corresponds to air in Hounsfield units (as Anders said). Now if you want to visualize the image, you have to apply a transfer function that will map HU scale to RGB for instance.