# Assign the Window centre and window width for dicom image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom, imshow

I have a Dicom image file in dcm format.In matlab by using **Dicomread** i got image data and by using **dicominfo** i got **window center** and **window width** of that dcm file. Now i want to display the image by using **imshow**  in figure.

My code is below,

```
ct = dicomread('E:\IM-0001-0001.dcm'); 
info = dicominfo('E:\IM-0001-0001.dcm');
figure
imshow(ct , [info.WindowCenter, info.WindowWidth]);
```

but it gives a error

> ```
>  Error using checkDisplayRange (line 20)
> HIGH must be greater than LOW.
> ```

I knew why this error was  came .it occur because of window center value is more than window width.

Now my question is

1.whether my code is right or wrong for assign the Window level and window width for dcm image?

2.How to assign the Window level and window width for dicom image when above condition occur?

Comment: Can you provide the image?

Comment: use this http://www.filedropper.com/im-0001-0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the highest and lowest value by

```
low = center - width / 2
high = center + width / 2
```

and use this values for imshow

```
imshow(ct, [low, high])
```

Comment: if i use above code then it gives wrong image ( like fully white or fully black or image is not clear) @ JohnnyQ

Comment: what are your window width / center values from dicominfo?

Comment: Window centre is [-600, 50] and Window width is [1200 350].

Comment: Well, in this case you should use (Center, Width) (-600,1200) or (50,350)

Comment: i am using as a [ -600,1200].

Comment: By using your code some of the image display correctly . but some of image not showing correctly( like fully white or fully black ).

Comment: you may have to consider rescale intercept and slope. check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756096/window-width-and-center-calculation-of-dicom-image/8765366#8765366] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756096/window-width-and-center-calculation-of-dicom-image/8765366#8765366)

Answer (score 0):

If I inspect that image with ImageMagick's `identify` command like this, I get the following...

```
identify -verbose IM-0001-0001.dcm | grep -i window

dcm:WindowCenter: 2856.4189453125
dcm:WindowWidth: 2475.0
```

I am inclined to believe these values since ImageMagick appears to extract the image perfectly well as below:

[image]

I would suggest you maybe check your window values with some other software.

Comment: I am not saying about  getting windows value. I asked question about how to set window values in imshow () function in matlab