# How to convert 12 bit DICOM image to 8 bit jpeg?

Tags: python, opencv, dicom, pydicom, 8-bit

I am trying to load DICOM files into python using the DICOM library. I have done the following

```
ds=dicom.read_file(r"C:\Users\Z003SPFR.AD005\ML\GLCM AND SVM\data\NECT\1.IMA")
#    # store the raw image data
DicomImage = ds.pixel_array
```

This gives me values that appear to be 12 bit, since the highest value obtained was around 3047 and lowest value was 0. Then I made my own mapping function to bring it to the range 0-255. I used the following code:

```
leftMin = 0
leftMax = np.amax(DicomImage)

rightMin = 0
rightMax = 255



def translate(value, leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax):
    # Figure out how 'wide' each range is
    leftSpan = leftMax - leftMin
    rightSpan = rightMax - rightMin

    # Convert the left range into a 0-1 range (float)
    valueScaled = float(value - leftMin) / float(leftSpan)

    # Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the right range.
    return rightMin + (valueScaled * rightSpan)

#print(translate(value, leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax))

       

def int12_to_int8(img):
    img_array = []

    for eachRow in img:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            img_array.append(translate(eachPix,leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax))
    img_array = np.array(img_array)
    img_array = img_array.reshape(512,512)  
    return img_array

correct_range_image = int12_to_int8(DicomImage)
```

After doing this, I realized that the array `img_array` was of type `uint16`. I wanted it as `uint8`. So I used the following line to convert to `uint8`:

```
cvuint8 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(correct_range_image)
```

Then I displayed the resulting image. But I received an image that didn't represent the original image very well. I have posted pictures of the original image and the converted image. How can I make the conversion better so that I get a better representation of the original image? Code I used to display is here :

```
cv2.imwrite('1.jpeg', cvuint8 )
cv2.imshow('image',cvuint8 )[enter image description here][1]
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

IMAGES

Converted Image
[image: Converted Image]

Original Image
[image: Original Image]

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73034604/5779732

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution for my problem.As mentioned above by Ahmed, DICOM plays around rescale slope, intercept and window level/width for proper display. After going through lot of documents, here is the way to render DICOM in Python using OpenCV,numpy and pydicom libraries which make all work easy

Code:
1.Read the image

```
ds=dicom.read_file("image_path")
# store the raw image data
img = ds.pixel_array
```

2. Use rescale slope and intercept information from the image header and translate it.

   rescale_slope=1
   rescale_intercept=-1024

   ```
   def translate(value,rescale_slope,rescale_intercept):

   return (value*rescale_slope)+rescale_intercept 

   def int12_to_int8(DicomImage):
       img_array = []

   for eachRow in DicomImage:
       for eachPix in eachRow:
           img_array.append(translate(eachPix,rescale_slope,rescale_intercept))
   img_array = np.array(img_array)
   img_array = img_array.reshape(512,512)  
   return img_array

   img_1 = int12_to_int8(img)
   ```

3.Use window level and width information from the image header to display in the proper range.

```
def get_LUT_value(data, window, level)

    return np.piecewise(data, 
        [data <= (level - 0.5 - (window-1)/2),
            data > (level - 0.5 + (window-1)/2)],
            [0, 255, lambda data: ((data - (level - 0.5))/(window-1) + 0.5)*(255-0)])

level=200
window=800

scaled_img=get_LUT_value(img, window, level)
```

4.Finally, with final image as wanted

```
scaled_img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(scaled_img)
cv2.imshow('image',scaled_img)
cv2.imwrite("hem.jpg",scaled_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer to http://dicom.nema.org/DICOM/2013/output/chtml/part04/sect_N.2.html to see how the medical image pixel data is rendered before its displayed 
not all mentioned concepts is applied but i assume your missing the importance of Window level and window Center Values .
read about Windowing equation here
[Window width and center calculation of DICOM image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756096/window-width-and-center-calculation-of-dicom-image)

So if you are trying to downgrade the bitDepth of the Image before its correctly rendered (losing least important data) , for sure you will get a bad image .
consider applying windowing on original data before conversion , you can play with [imageJ](https://imagej.net/Downloads) tool to see image operations (WL ,  Downgrading Depth) in action before writing the code for it

Answer (score 0):

Can follow this: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VolumeRC/AtlasConversionScripts/master/src/convertDICOM.py

where in simple way they have mentioned DICOM rendering using window level/width, rescale slope/intercept

```
def get_LUT_value(data, window, level,rescaleSlope,rescaleIntercept):
    return np.piecewise(data,
                        [((data * rescaleSlope) + rescaleIntercept) <= (level - 0.5 - (window - 1) / 2),
                         ((data * rescaleSlope) + rescaleIntercept) > (level - 0.5 + (window - 1) / 2)],
                        [0, 255, lambda VAL: ((((VAL * rescaleSlope) + rescaleIntercept) - (level - 0.5)) / (
                        window - 1) + 0.5) * (255 - 0)])
```